# Generate unique lists of random integers within range

Tags: haskell, random, random-seed

I am trying to write a function that will take two parameters, one that is the upper bound on the range that the random integer should be in. The other parameter is the number of lists of random numbers to be generated. Right now I am just trying to be able to generate lists of unique random numbers in a given range.

Using the following code, I can generate a random list of numbers, however, the numbers are of type `randomList 5 (0,10) :: IO [Int]` and not `[Int]`. The code also does not ensure that an integer is not repeated in a list.

```
import Test.QuickCheck

t :: Int -> (Int,Int) -> Gen [Int]
t n r = vectorOf n (choose r)

randomList n r = head `fmap` (sample' $ t n r)
```

I have looked at various StackOverflow answers although I still cannot find a solution. Many of the answers can only generate one random list with the same seed using `System.Random`

Comment: For a long list of unique random numbers use encryption and encrypt 0, 1, 2, ... with the same key.  Use 64 bit encryption for 64 bit numbers, 128 bit encryption for 128 bit numbers.  When you have a big list of unique random numbers then assign the numbers from the big list to your various sub-lists.

Comment: Just make your list like `[start..end]` and then [shuffle](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/232894/105433).

Comment: What is your reason for using Test.QuickCheck rather than [System.Random](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html) , if I may ask ?

Comment: @Redu That was useful for generating unique solutions but it gives the values as `IO [Int]`. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @jpmarinier It was just one of the ways that I found online to generate the solutions, I have looked at other ways using `System.Random` but I cannot get them to work as I need either.

Comment: @You can generate ramdom numbers purely but then you need a `StdGen` and to make one you will use `mkStdGen` function which will ask for a seed value... Now i can imagine you are asking "from where i will get a random seed?". Honestly for whatever purpose you need the shuffled array, please perform that task in IO monad like `shuffledList >>= return . doSomeFunkyStuff `. Now the `doSomeFunkyStuff` function is pure just like you have asked for. Where s the problem..?

Comment: @Redu I'm not sure I follow. Are you saying that I should do **everything** that I want to do with the shuffled array inside IO monad? My whole program is based on the data that I am trying to generate.

Comment: I would like to remind.. many Haskell programs start like `main :: IO ()`. But from another point of view... this resembles some JavaScript coders asking if they can I return a value from asynchgronous code. Yes, you have to perform your task within the IO monad like taking inputs from users, getting random values and returning results to display but all of the bits and pieces inside that. like `doSomeFunkyStuff` will be pure function code, possibly living in another module etc...

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with just [System.Random](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html).

```hs
getStdRandom (randomR (0, 100))
```

But you can also do it with [QuickCheck](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.13.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html). You can use `choose :: Random a => (a, a) -> Gen a` which can be used for any type that has a `Random` instance. You provide a range. Or with `elements :: [a] -> Gen a`. It takes a list of pure values (not in `Gen` yet), picks one and returns it in `Gen`.

```hs
generate $ choose (0,100)
generate $ elements [0..100]
```

Comment: All of the solutions are going to return `IO`. Let me know if you need help running these functions multiple times and going from `IO [IO Int]` to `IO [Int]`.

Comment: If you need something that is cryptographyically secure take a look at the package [cryptonite](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite).

Comment: Is there any way to generate `[Int]`? I have found a way that generates what I want, however, it gives `IO [Int]`

Comment: There is not a way a way to randomly generate `[Int]` without having `IO` involved. A random number generator needs to get a random seed by either reading the time or generating one created by a special hardware device. Reading time or data from a hardware device are both `IO` actions.

Comment: Oh, okay I see. Would I be able to convert `IO [Int]` to `[Int]`? Or is there a way to work with the data as if it is `[Int]`?

Comment: You can work with data like `IO [Int]` as if it were `[Int]` inside a function that is `IO a`, but that function must be `IO` at the end. Once you are in `IO` you cannot escape. For example `main :: IO ()`,
```
main  = do
  x <- generate $ choose (0,100)
  -- now you can use x as if it were just [Int]
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I have looked at various StackOverflow answers although I still cannot
>   find a solution.
>   Many of the answers can only generate one random list with the same seed using System.Random.

You can always reuse the new state of the random number generator to generate more samples, unless you use one of those functions that happen to "drop the ball", that is fail to return the new state along with the actual random sample.

I suggest using the `runRand` function as defined in [Control.Monad.Random](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.1.3/docs/Control-Monad-Random.html):

```
-- Run a random computation using the generator g, returning the result
-- and the updated generator.
runRand :: RandomGen g => Rand g a -> g -> (a, g)
```

This function takes a monadic *action* and a generator as parameters.

You mention you don't want any repetitions in the output list. This means you want a subset of a random *permutation* (a.k.a. a *shuffle*) of the input list. There is code for this in the [suitable page of the Haskell Wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Random_shuffle). This answer borrows shamelessly from that code, especially near the end of the page where it says "*Drawing without replacement*", hence no repetitions.

Below, I will use the example of a (bridge/poker) card game where the input list is `[0..51]` which models a standard ordered card deck with 52 cards. Definitely you do not want any repetitions in the output list, as having say two Kings of Diamonds in your hand is seriously frowned upon in that sort of things.

The general purpose code below consists mainly of 2 functions:

Function `swapElems` comes straight from the Wiki page. It has nothing to do with randomness and its purpose is just to "execute" a given permutation. Note that it is not absolutely necessary to use arrays for such a purpose. The code in [System.Random.Shuffle](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-shuffle-0.0.4/docs/System-Random-Shuffle.html) uses an ad hoc tree structure for the same task.

Function `partShuffle` generates the required monadic action, given an input list and a sample size (13 for a regular bridge hand of 13 cards out of 52).

```
import  Data.List    (sort, mapAccumL)
import  Data.Tuple   (swap)
import  Text.Printf  (printf)
import  Data.Array
import  Data.Array.MArray
import  Data.Array.ST
import  System.Random
import  Control.Monad.Random


swapElems  :: [a] -> [(Int, Int)] -> [a]
swapElems xs swaps = elems $ runSTArray (do
    arr <- newListArray (0, maxIx) xs
    mapM_ (swap arr) swaps
    return arr)
    where
        maxIx   = length xs - 1
        swap arr (i,j) = do
            vi <- readArray arr i
            vj <- readArray arr j
            writeArray arr i vj
            writeArray arr j vi


partShuffle :: MonadRandom mr => [a] -> Int -> mr [a]
partShuffle xs sampleSize =
  do
    let  maxIx     = length xs - 1
         ranStep i = do
                       j <- getRandomR (i, maxIx)
                       return (i, j)
    swapList  <- forM  [0 .. (min (maxIx - 1) sampleSize)]  ranStep
    let  xs2  =  swapElems xs swapList
    return $ take sampleSize xs2
```

Function `stUnfold` is not mentioned in the Wiki page, but it can be useful to automate the task of passing the generator state from one sample generation to the next, should you want the ability to generate an arbitrary number of samples:

```
stUnfold :: (s -> (a,s)) -> s -> Int -> ([a], s)
stUnfold go s0 count = let  auxList     =  replicate count ()
                            xgo state _ =  swap $ go state
                       in  swap  $  mapAccumL xgo s0 auxList
```

Type **s** in the signature stands for the type of the random number generator state.

```
 λ> stUnfold  (\n -> (n*n, n+1))  0  10
 ([0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81],10)
 λ>
```

We can now use these functions to generate say 10 random "hands" of 13 cards each. For illustration purposes, the first two ones are generated by passing the state of the generator around manually, and the next 8 ones are generated in one strike using the `stUnfold` utility function.

```
-- for prettyprinting purposes:
myShow :: [Int] -> String
myShow = concatMap  (printf "%02d ")


main = do
    let  -- setup random number generator:
         seed = 4242
         rng0 = mkStdGen seed
         -- standard bridge/poker card deck of 52 cards
         -- 13 cards out of 52, no replacement, 10 samples:
         itemCount   = 52
         deck        = [0 .. (itemCount-1)]
         sampleSize  = 13
         sampleCount = 10
    -- type of action1 is: Rand StdGen [Int]
    let action1          = partShuffle deck sampleSize

    -- passing random generator manually:
    let  (sample1, rng1a) = runRand action1 rng0
    putStrLn  $  myShow $ sample1
    let  (sample2, rng1b) = runRand action1 rng1a
    putStrLn  $  myShow $ sample2

    -- automated random generator passing:
    let  (samples, rng2) = stUnfold (runRand action1) rng1b (sampleCount - 2)
    mapM_  (\ls -> putStrLn  $  myShow ls)  samples
```

### Program output:

```
$ cards
49 38 15 14 03 24 22 02 37 43 44 31 39 
48 34 46 07 21 29 28 01 50 08 14 12 51 
27 31 48 19 20 01 16 04 15 35 30 50 46 
02 42 29 48 35 05 19 45 18 34 44 09 51 
37 47 49 05 19 16 50 21 02 22 39 11 12 
04 13 07 23 16 36 27 22 20 21 11 49 38 
45 02 27 36 13 04 14 12 11 26 09 38 00 
03 14 13 40 32 05 06 29 30 27 43 15 38 
48 15 00 04 11 10 13 07 21 36 09 38 37 
14 48 33 10 05 07 50 03 51 41 29 44 12 
$
```

Note that alternatively you can use a single monadic action that returns N samples. Such a monadic action is returned for example by the `grabble` function in the Wiki page.

It is also possible,once you have a monadic action generating one sample, to obtain an action generating N samples using the [replicateM](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=replicateM) function. The following code obscures a little bit what happens under the hood, but it does produce exactly the same output as above.

```
    let action1   =  partShuffle deck sampleSize
        action10  =  replicateM 10 action1
    let (samples, rng3) = runRand action10 rng0
    mapM_  (\ls -> putStrLn  $  myShow ls)  samples
```